# Use Postfix to forward mail to a domain to the same address at a different domain

Tags: postfix

Is there a way to configure Postfix to accept any mail for a domain (catch-all), and then forward that email to the same recipient at a different domain, ignorant of whether the recipient actually exists?

I use Postfix with a MySQL backing for virtual accounts.

Answer (score 8):

No this is not directly possible. There is one exception how it can work described in http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#luser_relay

Another crude solution would be to use SQL (substr + concat) to handle this for you in the `virtual_alias_maps`.

**Edit**:
Oh. There is one last possibility. Use the [policy delegation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html) mechanism and return `REDIRECT localpart@other-domain.example` where you need it and `DUNNO` if you don't want to rewrite.

**Edit 2**:
Inspired by Squidly (but his solution does not work!) you can setup

```
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/forward_user.pcre, ...
```

and in that file put

```
/^(.*)@adomain\.example/    $(1)@other-domain.example
```

(Watch out for the escaped dot (\.) in the first column.) Personally I would prefer this version.

Comment: the third solution worked for me. however i had to install the `postfix-pcre` package (ubuntu 12.10)

Answer (score 1):

The pcre table type is unavailable on my system, so I did the following:

- In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

  ```
  virtual_alias_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual
  ```
- In `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

  ```
  /^([^@]*)@olddomain/ $(1)@newdomain
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly possible? I found it very simple and direct with no SQL, regular expressions, or policy mechanisms.

In `main.cf`:

```
virtual_alias_domains = alias-destination1.com alias-destination2.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

In `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
# I want @true-destination.com to have two incoming aliases
@alias-destination1.com @true-destination.com
@alias-destination2.com @true-destination.com
```

Sending a test e-mail from the server:

```
# telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.myserver.com ESMTP Postfix
HELO smtp.myserver.com
250 smtp.myserver.com
MAIL FROM:<somebody@gmail.com>
RCPT TO:<anyuser@alias-destination1.com>
250 2.1.5 Ok
DATA
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Message-ID: <4DC3723F.8010907@myserver.com>                                                                                                               
Date: Thu, 05 May 2011 23:59:59 -0400                                                                                                                    
From: Some Body <somebody@gmail.com>                                                                                                                   
To: anyuser@alias-destination1.com                                                                                                                                
Subject: Hello                                                                                                                                           
Just testing.                                                                                                                                            
.
```

And the actual result in mail.log (I have amavis on port 10025 running):

```
Apr  6 22:39:43 smtp-a postfix/smtpd[4411]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr  6 22:39:43 smtp-a postfix/smtpd[4411]: 6B47641AF2: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr  6 22:39:43 smtp-a postfix/cleanup[3706]: 6B47641AF2: message-id=<4DC3723F.8010907@myserver.com>
Apr  6 22:39:43 smtp-a postfix/qmgr[3681]: 6B47641AF2: from=<somebody@gmail.com>, size=1115, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  6 22:39:43 smtp-a postfix/smtpd[4411]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr  6 22:39:43 smtp-a amavis-incoming[2159]: (02159-13) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal}, LOCAL [127.0.0.1]:42426 [127.0.0.1] <somebody@gmail.com> -> <anyuser@alias-destination1.com>, Queue-ID: 5C61F41AE5, Message-ID: <4DC3723F.8010907@myserver.com>, mail_id: hUbzH1PtXlzl, Hits: 2.605, size: 394, queued_as: 6B47641AF2, 1224 ms
Apr  6 22:39:43 smtp-a postfix/lmtp[3687]: 5C61F41AE5: to=<anyuser@alias-destination1.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=25, delays=24/0/0/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6B47641AF2)
Apr  6 22:39:43 smtp-a postfix/qmgr[3681]: 5C61F41AE5: removed
```

Key line separated for emphasis:

```
Apr  6 22:39:43 smtp-a postfix/smtp[3684]: 6B47641AF2: to=<anyuser@true-destination.com>, orig_to=<anyuser@alias-destination1.com>, relay=10.0.0.245[10.0.0.245]:2525, delay=0.03, delays=0.01/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 705AA40459)
Apr  6 22:39:43 smtp-a postfix/qmgr[3681]: 6B47641AF2: removed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL as the storage end, I believe that you can specify a catch all forward like this:

Table Forwardings

```
| source       | destination   |
|==============|===============|
| @example.com | @yoursite.com |
```

If I read the documentation right, it would mean that user1@example.com will now be forwarded to user1@yoursite.com, etc.

I found this in [this howtoforge tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual_postfix_mysql_quota_courier_p5)

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how you setup your Postfix you may be able to use an alias to forward all mail.

*edit*

Also you can setup a redirect that will do it for you easily.

In /etc/postfix/main.cf add this:

```
recipient_bcc_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/forward_bcc.pcre
```

Then in /etc/postfix/forward_bcc.pcre add this:

```
/^user@olddomain.com/ user@newdomain.com
```

This is a bit of a hack but it will work for forwarding specific users from one domain to another.

You also may want to look at [this](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html) page for how to do some rewriting within Postfix it's self.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I know I can specify `@somedomain.com` to forward all mail to a *specific* address, but I want to know if I can forward to the *same* recipient.

Comment: in /etc/aliases set it up like this.
$username: $username@newdomain.com

Comment: @Squidly Your edit is not a regular expression and will not work. You comment about /etc/aliases will not work as the OP has only virtual users.

Comment: @mailq. That is LIVE on *MY* server right now. It works perfectly for multiple redirects. Also he did not say these were ONLY virtual users. It was also giving options to look at.