# Redirecting wildcard email to one email with postfix

Tags: email, postfix, email-bounces, wildcard

I'm creating a bounce email system where addressees can reply to messages on my site.

However when the email are sent to the user containing the previous message, the `Reply-To` field contains an address like this `notification-message-988742@mysite.com` (which contains the ID at the end).

If the user replies, the reply message will be sent back to `notification-message-988742@mysite.com` which of course, doesn't have its own mailbox, except the `notification@mysite.com`.

How would I redirect all incoming messages coming from a specific wildcard `notification-message-*@mysite.com` to `notification@mysite.com`? I did some research, but no solid part worked, including the `luser_relay = notification@mysite.com` and putting `notification-message-*` in the postfix aliases table, the `notification@` has a Maildir, so the mail would go into it.

A concept diagram:

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Use pcre http://serverfault.com/questions/313050/use-postfix-to-forward-mail-to-a-domain-to-the-same-address-at-a-different-domai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to solve this using [`recipient_delimiter`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter).

If you don't mind using slightly different `Reply-To` addresses, you can set:

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```

in your config, and then mail to e.g. `notification+message-988742@mysite.com` (note the `+`) will be delivered to the `notification` user (assuming there are no more-specific rules/users matching `notification+message-988742`).

You *could* try setting `recipient_delimiter = -` (so that you could use the `Reply-To` headers as they are in the question) but I'm not sure how that would work with multiple instances of the delimiter on the left-hand side, and I don't have a Postfix to hand to check.

Answer (score 14):

As have said mschuett, you can use regexp

First check that postfix supports regexp:

```
root @ mail / #  postconf -m | grep regexp
regexp
```

Create the file /etc/postfix/aliases-regexp and add to it your regexp

```
root @ mail / #  cat /etc/postfix/aliases-regexp
/notification-message-[0-9]+@example\.net/ notification@example.net
```

Run postmap and check whether it works:

```
root @ mail / #  postmap /etc/postfix/aliases-regexp
root @ mail / #  postmap -q notification-message-123123@example.net regexp:/etc/postfix/aliases-regexp
notification@example.net
```

If everything is OK, add this file to your alias database

Example:

```
root @ mail / #  cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep ^alias_maps
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases regexp:/etc/postfix/aliases-regexp
```

If you are using virtual domains, add this file to your virtual_alias_maps

Example:

```
root @ mail / #  cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep ^virtual_alias_maps
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/alias.conf regexp:/etc/postfix/aliases-regexp
```

Do not forget to restart postfix.

Good luck!

Comment: Is it possible to store the regex aliases in a database like MySQL or sqlite3, like you do with the `mysql:` lookup table?

Comment: @rednaw Yes, definitely possible (and preferable IMO)! Just modify the **``query``** used in the ``mysql-virtual-aliases.cf`` file to something like ``query = SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE is_regexp=0 AND source='%s' OR is_regexp=1 AND '%s' REGEXP CONCAT('^',source,'$')`` as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23267975/1057616). This way, you can use both regexp aliases and non-regexp aliases in the same table with a simple database flag (`is_regexp`). Pretty sweet.

Comment: @NickMerrill plase considered adding your comment as an answer.

Comment: `postconf-m` misses a white space. Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to fix it. :( ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233 )

Answer (score 3):

Alias maps ([virtual](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html), [local](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html), ...) will work in combination with the [regexp_table](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) format. But if you have compiled in PCRE, then you can also use the pcre_table format.

Otherwise you should search for "Postfix catch-all" which is a bit more greedy.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can do this?

Comment: Just use virtual_alias_maps with a regexp_table `/notification-message-[0-9]*@mysite.com/  notification@mysite.com`

Answer (score 0):

Create a rule using "with specific words in the sender's address."  It will accept multiple words as "or" but I don't see how to do it with an "and."  Perhaps this gets you far enough.